# How do I enumerate receivers in my user interface?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromecast

Is there a good way to fetch a list of Chromecast receivers for use by my user interface?

An older version of the CC API offered code like this: ([found here](https://github.com/pjjanak/chromecast-hello-world/blob/master/sender/index.html))

```
    var cast_api = new cast.Api();
    cast_api.addReceiverListener('APP ID', onReceiverList);

    ...

  onReceiverList = function(list) {
    if (list.length > 0) {
         /* list of receiver identities available here */
    }
  }
```

But this seems to be missing from the latest api.  What's the best way to do that in early 2015?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926127/i-used-to-be-able-to-get-a-receiver-list-in-the-chromecast-beta-now-i-cant

Answer (score 0):

Discovery of Cast devices is handled by the Cast Extension and the cast button that is made available by that extension. You can learn more about that in our [docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender). You can find a number of samples on our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/googlecast) as well.

Comment: Thanks, @AliNaddaf. I'm aware of the Cast button in the extension; I'm looking to show the enumerated receivers in a different place in my UI. Think of it as a management UI. Is that possible?

Comment: No, there is no api or callback for you to directly get the list of devices. You can put a cast button anywhere you want and hook it up so that clicking on that shows the list of devices but this enumeration and display of the list is handled by the extension.

Comment: Are you sure? In the Android application, "LocalCast", they are using a custom view to show CC devices, which is definitely not the default, Cast SDk implementation. So there must be a way to get a list of devices...

Comment: In Android and iOS SDK it is possible but not in Chrome SDK